# Problemas com ordenação dentro de um repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDocumentosRepeater" runat="server"><%--onitemdatabound="listaDocumentosRepeater_ItemDataBound"--%>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <legend class="uppercase">Lista de documentos</legend>
        <table id="tabelaUpload" class="uploadBens">
            <thead>
                <th width="200">
                    Tipo de documento
                </th>
                <th width="200">
                    Escolha o arquivo
                </th>
                <th>
                    Documentos enviados
                </th>
            </thead>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdDocumento" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdDocumentoBem")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdTipoDocumento" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CdTipoDocumentoBem")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfDsPathDocumento" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DsPathDocumento")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfNmObrigatorio" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("NmTipoObrigatorio")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfForcarLiberacao" runat="server" Value="0" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblNmTipoDocumento" CssClass="tipoDocumento" Text='<%# Eval("NmTipoDocumentoBem")%>' runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblObrigatorio" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NmTipoObrigatorio")%>' Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="ajusteTdIe">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="fiuDocumentoUpload" runat="server" CssClass="acessos" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="/UpLoads/<%# Eval("DsPathDocumento")%>" class="linkUpload"><%# Eval("NmTipoDocumentoDown")%></a>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDtCriacao" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DtCriacao")%>' Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblNmUsuario" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NmUsuario")%>' Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRecebeMotivoReprovacao" Text='<%# Eval("NmTipoMotivoRecusaBem")%>' runat="server" CssClass="motivoEscolhido" Visible="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Esse `repeater` ele mostra no lado esquerdo da tela uma série de documentos para ser carregados(nome deles, tipo, DUT, Nota Fiscal e etc). Na `<TD>` central existe um botão para fazer o upload do documento. E na `<TD>` da direita, ele mostra o doumento carregado. Bem o que acontece, é que à medida que eu vou carregando os documentos, ele vai subindo para a parte superior da tela assim: Digamos que eu tenho uma lista de 5 documentos a serem carregados. O primeito da lista seria Nota Fiscal e o último seria DUT. Se eu carregar o DUT primeiro, após a carga, ele passa a ser o primeiro e não quinto como deveria. O problema é que o usuário carrega e ao mudar de posição no grid, o usuário acha que carregou o errado e isso causa um desonforto enorme. O problema que a entidade e a procedure que carrega, não tem nenhum `Order By` e gostaria de saber se há uma forma de não alterar a posição dos mesmos na tela. Forçar um não ordenamento dos campos.

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui fazer no repeater, aí acrescentei mais um campo somente para ordenar por ele, foi o único recurso que consegui. No repeater não consegui fazer.